# Is there a way to totally reset Ignite state?

Tags: java, junit, ignite

I've implemented IgniteResourse that starts and stops Ignite for integration tests with JUnit. The problem is that it needs a lot of time to start a node. Is there a way to totally reset Ignite state between tests without full restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running under Windows? I'm asking because Ignite runs thousands of unit tests for every code change, which start tens of thousands of Ignite instance, and it works pretty fast. I assume the time to start non-persistent Ignite instance is around 100ms.

You should figure out what slows you down in this use case. Is it Multicast discovery? Please switch to Static discovery with `shared=true` and small `portRange` for best performance.

Comment: Yes, I'm. In CI environment it takes twice less time to run the these tests: about 4 seconds per test. I use TcpDiscoverySpi 

`new TcpDiscoverySpi().setIpFinder(new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder().setAddresses("127.0.0.1:47500..47502"))`

Comment: You can use `127.0.0.1:47500` and shared IP finder for best performance.